How to denote Blazor component is abstract using only .razor file?
When I have .razor.cs file it is no brainer, but how to tell given Blazor component is abstract when having only .razor file?
I checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0 but didn't find anything relevant.

An abstract razor component? How would the markup blend between the parent and child classes?

@gunr2171 I don't understand you question, but I sense you doubt abstract components are valid entities. I assure you they are valid, I use them quite often the same way I use abstract types in general (outside Blazor scope).

Right, and it makes sense to use a code file to make an abstract component. But how would that make sense using a markup file? If you use a .razor file, you have markup, even if it's empty. How would you merge the markup of BaseComponent.razor with ChildComponent.razor?

Abstract does not mean empty. That's first. The second, I use the following code, and it applies in general when using parent-child relation, so it is not limited to abstract parent -- @{ base.BuildRenderTree(__builder); }.

There's no way to denote in .razor. And I think abstract component is not necessary. You could use virtual method to be override in derived component. Such as following:
AbstractComponent.razor
<p>@GetContent()</p>
@code {
    protected virtual string GetContent(){ return ""; }
}

DerivedComponent.razor
@inherits AbstractComponent
@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
@code {
    protected override string GetContent()
    {
        return "This is the derived content.";
    }
}


Thank you for the answer. The need for abstract depends on the case (Blazor does not make anything here special). What you suggest is basically a hack just to get away without abstract.
